# Adicionar dois intervalos em uma busca

Tags: mysql

Estou precisando criar uma consulta que busque um chamado de acordo com o intervalo de tempo.

Exemplo: Um funcionário abre um chamado no sistema, mas ele só será mostrado caso ele fique em aberto de 2 a 4 horas.

Estou usando este código, porém não obtive resultado.

```
SELECT date FROM db WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 HOUR) AND DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 4 HOUR) AND status='1';
```

Comment: Consegui descobrir:
SELECT date FROM db WHERE date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR) AND DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 4 HOUR) AND status='1';

Comment: Conseguiu descobrir, ou ainda está com o problema?
Caso descobriu, deleta o seu post.